# How to calculate an arbitrary power/root?

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point, exponent

I have a application which needs to raise a number to a fractional power.  The target platform is an FPGA and I can get estimates on an FPU size for it, but I need an algorithm for raising a number to a fractional power just for a feasibility study.  I'm assuming floating point as a worst case, I expect in practice we will be able to use short cuts, but for now I want to show that worst case can be implemented on our part.

Thought I'd ask here and see if there were any common methods that I could checkout. I know there are software methods of doing this, I want just a reasonably efficient algorithm to start with.  I'll worry about the FPGA implementation.

Answer (score 8):

Is your range of inputs arbitrary, or known within a certain range?

in either case, x<sup>m</sup> = exp(m log x), so if you can create functions to evaluate exp(x) and log(x) and have a multiply, you're probably all set.

You'll have to figure out how you want to handle nonpositive values of x.

(hint for log(x): if this is [IEEE-754 floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), shift the significand if necessary until you end up with a range of numbers between 2<sup>k</sup> and 2<sup>k+1</sup> for some value K. This lets you deal with a 2:1 range which isn't too hard to approximate with polynomials. Then you just have a small number of possibilities to handle for the exponent and the shift number.

Corresponding hint for exp(x): write x = k+b where 0 <= b < 1 and k is an integer. Then exp(x) = exp(k)*exp(b); b has limited range and k has a limited number of discrete possibilities.)

(hint #2: the numbers probably work out better for x<sup>m</sup> = g(m f(x)) where f(x) = log<sub>2</sub>x and g(x) = 2<sup>x</sup>.)

Comment: I'm assuming arbitrary for now, I have to read some more of the system's theory behind the calculation were performing. Right now were just trying to propose a solution to the customer. I just want to analytically prove it CAN be done on our system.

Comment: +1.  I worked on a weird runtime a while back that lacked a full FP library but provided frexp/ldexp routines to separate and recombine the exponent and mantissa; from this, building the standard FP functions was fairly straightforward.

Comment: Actually for one case in particular it looks like the exponent is going to be > 1.  I'm not sure that holds true for all cases.

Answer (score 6):

As Jason S said, this is done using the identity x<sup>m</sup> = exp(m log x). In practice though, you will have to deal with truncation errors.
I think that the way this is usually done is

1. Use this identity: x<sup>m</sup> = (2<sup>n</sup> * x / 2<sup>n</sup>)<sup>m</sup> = 2<sup>nm</sup> * (x/2<sup>n</sup>)<sup>m</sup> and find an integer n such that 1 <= x/2<sup>n</sup> < 2.
2. Calculate t = log2(x / 2<sup>n</sup>). This can be done either using a sufficiently high degree Taylor expansion, or with good ol' Newton-Raphson. You have to make sure that the maximum error over the interval [1, 2[ is not too large for you.
3. Calculate u = nm + tm.
4. Our goal is now to calculate 2<sup>u</sup>. Use the fact that 2<sup>u</sup> = 2<sup>v</sup> * 2<sup>u-v</sup> and find an integer v such that 0 <= u-v < 1.
5. Calculate w = 2<sup>u-v</sup>, again using our friend Taylor or Newton-Raphson. The interval of interest is 0 <= u-v < 1.
6. Your answer is now 2<sup>v</sup> * w.

Comment: How exactly do you use newton raphson to calc a log function?  I can find divison algo using it, but there is too much "noise" on google to find how to calc log using it.

Comment: I think I remember from my calculation theory that it's possible, but I might be wrong. I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: The same you use it to calculate any function - it's basically a numerical solver for f(x) = 0, given a pair of starting points x1, x2 and a guarantee that the solution lies between.