# Multiplication Algorithm for multipliers of powers of ten

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to optimize some division algorithm for large numbers, but this is dependent on how fast i can multiply the divisor with powers of ten: `divisor * power(10, n)` where n is a positive integer. i know about some optimized multiplication algorithms such as the use of FFT, but that still goes though `O(nlog(n))`, but am looking for something optimized for this case only, otherwise my algorithm performance will have performance greater than `O(nlog(n))`. Any idea if there is an optimization for this special case?

Note that i intend to implement this in C++.

Comment: Sadly, I can't help much, but why are you working with powers of ten instead of the more natural powers of two ?

Comment: You might try precalculating `power(10, n)` for the range of values of `n` you might encounter (given there can only be a few thousand before `double`'s range's exhausted): put them into an array for direct indexing by `n`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: You should put some more details on it and put it as an answer, it is a good solution [IMO], which will probably be easier to implement and faster then FFT or other solutions.

Comment: @J.N: i am not doing multiplication at the digital level, if so, it would have been very easy (shifting the bits in O(n)). Also, the integers i want to work with may have millions of digits. multiplication in binary would also break the algorithm i want to implement besides the fact that the representation of the large integer in binary is cumbersome due to the fact that it is not a single integer but an array of built in integer types.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Actually it can be much larger, millions of digits. Multiplying several digit number with 10^100 or larger. But this probably is a good idea, can decide to do it in steps lower than the double range

Comment: Frankly I don't see how an indexing approach ( or as a matter of fact, any software approach ) will beat the natural instruction. div while slower than mul still churns heck of a lot faster than table indexing on all architectures I've run into this millennium. If anything I'd take a look at what sort of enhanced instruction set you have access to ( altivec, SSE etc ), and try to vectorize your problem instead. EDIT: Sorry, missed that you need larger range than builtins.

Comment: If you want to go fast, you have no choice but speaking a language your computer understands, that is binary. Every step of translation will cost you an order of magnitude in performance.

Comment: Providing ideas on how your builtin integer work will help people give you better answers.

Comment: the large integer is represented as an array to "base 10^10", that is the largest element in the array can be '10^10 - 1', where element[0] is the least significant element and element[length-1] is the most significant element. I chose that maximum in order to simply addition and subtractions and avoid unsigned integer addition overflow, the most common operations.

Comment: @maress, `10^10` is approximately `2^(33.2)`. That seems to me as one of the worst possible bases available. Please take the time to elaborate your motivations and constraints.

Comment: @jgroenen, you've missed the `power(10, n)` part.

Comment: @jgroenen: thanks! I have been looking for something like this, and could not arrive at that shifting. It seems pretty good, and may be i can tweak my implementation to use a modified version for faster multiplication (in thousands)

Comment: @avakar: it is a matter of representation. certainly i cannot represent a million digit integer as a single digit in modern computers. So i represent it in as an array, with each array component maximum value being (CORRECTION) 10^9 - 1.

Comment: @maress, the thing everyone is questioning is why you didn't choose the maximum value of `2^32`, or even `2^31` if you insist on having room for overflow? Why did you choose such an esoteric base as `10^9`?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882706/how-can-i-write-a-power-function-myself) out!

Comment: @avakar 999,999,999 to be maxmimum, so that i have an easy carry and borrow during addition and subtraction (am doing this operations in base 10 actually). If you can explain why 2^31 = 2147483648 would be more appropriate than what i have chosen for this operations?

Comment: @maress, because in base `2^31`, to add digits `a` and `b` you simply compute `(a+b)&0x7fffffff` for the result digit and `(a+b)>>31` for carry. That is much faster than `(a+b)%1000000000` and `(a+b)/1000000000`. In other words, dividing by a power of 2 is much faster than dividing by any other number. You should read more about how bigint libraries are done in practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you use array to store large numbers, you can copy the divisor to a new array and add n zeros to the end of it. The new array is the the answer you want. The complexity is O(n).