# math.h pow vs manual power performance

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, time, math.h

I just was wondering how the `pow` function of the `math.h` library works, does it implement the simplest sequencial algorithm or does it use another one else?

I just know the repeated squaring algorithm, which reports **O(log n)**, maybe this is the implemented algorithm by the `pow` function?

So I just made some tests using the sequential algorithm vs `pow` and found out that the first version is almost 3 times faster than the second. Does calling functions really punish that much the performance of this test? Why?

Any other comments explaining what's happening, or how `pow` is implemented are welcome.

**EDIT:** I was wrong, `pow` is 3 times **faster** than the sequential algorithm.

Comment: That is completely up to whoever wrote your standard library.  Which one are you using? Also, `pow()` works on floating-point.

Comment: Just open math.f file and check it? It is source code, not compiled lib after all.

Comment: It depends on arguments. Your `pow` is probably less general and less accurate.

Comment: At a guess, on x86 a typical implementation may well look like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2882761/179910).

Comment: I hate adding a link but this seems to be a good resource as I was curious as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1

Comment: I use the MinGW32 libraries. Opening the math.h file doesn't help, obviously.

Comment: @dabadaba: how reading source code of function you are wondering about can not help?

Comment: I assume repeated squaring will not continue to outperform pow for large values of x and y

Comment: @PTwr because I can't see the implementation?

Comment: Does your repeated squaring algorithm handle `pow(2, 0.5)` and correctly return the square root of 2?

Comment: I am not using a repeated squaring algorithm of my own, if you read my post I say I am using sequencial algorithm of my own vs math.h pow function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation of `pow()` in `math.h` is a lot more complex than that - take a look at this freely available implementation ([link](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c)).

A problem with repeated squaring is that it is not general enough to deal with fractional powers. The `pow()` from `math.h` must deal with it, so it is necessarily slower on some of the test cases. However, since the repeated squaring function does not have the same functionality, the comparison is not apples-to-apples.

Generally speaking, it is much easier to optimize for performance if you do not need to handle the general case. For example, if you never raise numbers to fractional powers, you could potentially make an algorithm that beats the library function 3:1 in a micro-benchmark. This should come with understanding that the applicability of the "faster" function is not as wide.

Answer (score 2):

According to the ANSI C99 standard, section 7.12.7.4:

> **Description**
>
> The `pow` functions compute `x` raised to the power `y`. A domain error occurs if `x` is finite and negative and `y` is finite and not an integer value. A domain error may occur if `x` is zero and `y` is less than or equal to zero.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `pow` functions return `x^y`.

In other words, it doesn’t specify the exact algorithm to be used. You’d have to look at the source code for the C/C++ standard library that you’re using. I would assume most library authors have used a highly-optimized algorithm.

**Update:** In comments, you say that you are using MinGW32. That links against Microsoft’s runtime, msvcrt. Although it’s not open source, looking at [Microsoft’s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze.aspx) all we know is that it uses SSE2. It’s likely very efficient.