# Write Pow Function Without math.h in C

Tags: c, function, recursion, pow

Hi I want to write a code for a pow function without using math.h libary.

**How is this code?how can i fix it when b<0**

```
    int MyPow(int a,int b){
      if(b<0)      
        return 1 / MyPow (a,-b)
      else if(b==0)
        return 1;
      else if(b==1)
        return a;
      else
        return a*MyPow(a,b-1)
    }
```

Comment: what happens when `b<0`?

Comment: @Jayesh linux system that I write there didnt have Math.h

Comment: that's not the issue... what he means is 'What is this code doing that deviates from your expectations?', 'What does it return, and what should it return', that sort of thing.

Comment: @Omer math.h is a standard header, i wonder why it was not available ?

Comment: I think you should check `if (a==0) { return 0; }` and `if (b==0||a==1) { return 1; }` and `if (b==1) { return a; }` and finaly `return myPow(a*a, b/2) * ((b%2==0) ? 1 : a);`

Comment: @Psychemaster I just asked if its good function of pow and how can I upgrade this function

Comment: As a suggestion try exponentiation by squaring algorithm, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring. It's much faster `O(log2(n))` than "naive" method. This may teach you recursion as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Omer-kindly re-visit my code! I have updated it as it contained a minor flaw! Please re-edit your code!

Comment: If `b < 0`, then the result isn't `int`. Pow(1, -2) is 0.25. So without changing the return type it isn't really possible to return anything useful for `b<0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I write a power function myself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882706/how-can-i-write-a-power-function-myself)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck The original code had no branch for `b<0` so it would most likely have caused a stack overflow (tail recursion optimisation is not possible here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems perfect except for one condition :- `when b<0`.

For b<0,simply return

```
return (1.0/a)*MyPow(a,abs(b)-1);   //where  abs(b) is  absolute value of b.
```

OR

```
return (1.0/a)*(MyPow(a,b+1));
```

Also,your definition of function is not valid for performing negative exponentiation,you should change it to

```
float MyPow(int a,int b)
```

Comment: Why not just 1 / MyPow (a, -b) ?

Comment: `1/MyPow(a,-b)` will be `0` almost always (unless `b==1`, and then it would be `1`).

Comment: @shekharsuman: Because all involved values have type `int`. Integer division of `1` by `something` will return `0` if `something` is anything but `1` or `0`.

Comment: Ahh!!! @bitmask--THANKS,I couldn't believe I have committed this mistake! THANKS again for reminding...

Comment: Still his function returns int, so it still will be 0 for negative b...

Comment: Yeah,he obviously needs to change the return type of his function from int to float---it's obvious! He'll do/manage that.

Comment: @gnasher729-I guess your suggestion couldn't be recursively implemented to obtain negative power in this case.If I am wrong,please clarify...

Answer (score 3):

Probably best way I think,   [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

```
int pow(int base, int exp)
    {
      if(exp < 0)
        return -1;

        int result = 1;
        while (exp)
        {
            if (exp & 1)
                result *= base;
            exp >>= 1;
            base *= base;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Good performance, since complexity is `O(log(exp))`. Note that it doesn't handle cases where `exp < 0`.

Comment: Yes you are right @KlasLindbäck. Any suggestion to make it work for `exp < 0` without compromising complexity?

Comment: As long as the return type is `int`, using a negative exponent is meaningless since the result will be truncated to 0. Otherwise, the normal solution to a negative exponent is: `return 1.0/pow(base, -exp)`

Comment: actually I was asking for return type double...thanks that helped

Answer (score 0):

A solution with less complexity taken from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/

```
float power(float x, int y)
{
    float temp;
    if( y == 0)
       return 1;
    temp = power(x, y/2);       
    if (y%2 == 0)
        return temp*temp;
    else
    {
        if(y > 0)
            return x*temp*temp;
        else
            return (temp*temp)/x;
    }
}
```