# Extract a number from a position in C

Tags: c, math

In this exercise he asks me to create a function
`Number_pos (N, pos, m)` which allows to extract a number composed of `m` digits
from position `pos` using functions.

Example:
N = 12345, pos = 2, m = 3
Number_pos (N, pos, m) = 234

I use an `Extraxt_from_position` function which extracts a number from a given position, then I use a function which calculates the number of digits of the number to extract, then I have a mirror function which inverts the number and I do the successive division until the number of digits are equal to the number of digits of the number we want to extract.

The problem is: forbidden to use mirror function, can you help me

```
int Extract_from_position(int n, int r)
{
  int m = 0, s = 0;
  while (n != 0)
  {
    m = n % 10;
    s++;
    if (s == r)
    {
      return n;
    }
    n = n / 10;
  }
}

int Number_of_digits(int n)
{
  int m = 0, s = 0;
  while (n != 0)
  {
    m = n % 10;
    s++;
    n = n / 10;
  }
  return s;
}

int Mirror(int n)
{
  int m = 0, s = 0;
  while (n != 0)
  {
    m = n % 10;
    s = s * 10 + m;
    n = n / 10;
  }
  return s;
}

int Number_Pos(int N, int pos, int m)
{
  int x = Extract_from_position(N, pos);
  int y = 0;
  int R = Mirror(x);
  int T = Number_of_digits(R);
  while (T >= m + 1)
  {
    y = R % 10;
    R = R / 10;
    T--;
  }
  return Mirror(R);
}

int main()
{
  int n, pos, nbcx;
  printf("Give n :");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Give the position :");
  scanf("%d", &pos);
  printf("give the number of digits of the number to extract :");
  scanf("%d", &nbcx);
  printf("\nThe result after the amber extract from position %d on the right and the number of digits %d is : %d  \n", pos, nbcx, Number_Pos(n, pos, nbcx));
}
```

Comment: Seems like you could divide to get rid of digits on the right you did not want and then mod to get rid of the digits on the left you don't want.

Comment: Don't use mirror function

Comment: How to mod to get rid of the digits on the left you don't want?

Comment: Note : `Extract_from_position(0,0)` never specifies what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work. I trim the digits you don't want on the right then mod to mask off the digits on the left you don't want.

Based on your sample I assume that `pos` is 1-based. If not there's a comment on the code you would need to remove.

You'd probably want to add error checking to make sure that `pos` and `num_digits` are valid for the given `N`, but that's an exercise for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Number_of_digits(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

int Number_Pos(int N, int pos, int num_digits)
{
    int len = Number_of_digits(N);
    pos -= 1; //pos is 1 based.

    //trim right side
    for (int i = 0; i < len - num_digits - pos; ++i)
    {
        N /= 10;
    }

    //calculate mod to keep num_digits.
    int m = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_digits - 1; ++i)
    {
        m *= 10;
    }

    return N % m;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 1234567;
    int pos = 2;
    int num_digits = 3;
    int result = Number_Pos(n, pos, num_digits);
    printf("Num: %d, Pos: %d, Digits: %d - Result: %d\n", n, pos, num_digits, result);

    pos = 3;
    num_digits = 4;
    result = Number_Pos(n, pos, num_digits);
    printf("Num: %d, Pos: %d, Digits: %d - Result: %d\n", n, pos, num_digits, result);

    pos = 1;
    num_digits = 4;
    result = Number_Pos(n, pos, num_digits);
    printf("Num: %d, Pos: %d, Digits: %d - Result: %d\n", n, pos, num_digits, result);

    pos = 6;
    num_digits = 2;
    result = Number_Pos(n, pos, num_digits);
    printf("Num: %d, Pos: %d, Digits: %d - Result: %d\n", n, pos, num_digits, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Num: 1234567, Pos: 2, Digits: 3 - Result: 234
Num: 1234567, Pos: 3, Digits: 4 - Result: 3456
Num: 1234567, Pos: 1, Digits: 4 - Result: 1234
Num: 1234567, Pos: 6, Digits: 2 - Result: 67
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Count from right**
If you want count the digits from right, the `NumberPos` function will be just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int NumberPos(int N, int pos, int m)
{
    int trc = (int)(N / (int)pow(10, pos - 1));
    trc = trc % (int)pow(10, m);
    return trc;
}

int main()
{
  int n, pos, nbcx;
  printf("Give n :");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Give the position :");
  scanf("%d", &pos);
  printf("give the number of digits of the number to extract :");
  scanf("%d", &nbcx);
  printf("\nThe result after the amber extract from position %d on the right and the number of digits %d is : %d  \n", pos, nbcx, NumberPos(n, pos, nbcx));
}
```

And the output will be, for example:

```
Give n :1234567 
Give the position :3
give the number of digits of the number to extract :2

The result after the amber extract from position 3 on the right and the number of digits 2 is : 45
```

---

**OLD:** This could be a solution (in basically 4 line):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int NumberPos(int N, int pos, int m)
{
    int digit = floor(log10(abs(N))) + 1;
    int trc = N % (int)pow(10, digit - pos + 1);
    digit = floor(log10(abs(trc))) + 1;
    trc = (int)(trc / (int)pow(10, digit - m));
    return trc;
}

int main()
{
  int n, pos, nbcx;
  printf("Give n :");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Give the position :");
  scanf("%d", &pos);
  printf("give the number of digits of the number to extract :");
  scanf("%d", &nbcx);
  printf("\nThe result after the amber extract from position %d on the right and the number of digits %d is : %d  \n", pos, nbcx, NumberPos(n, pos, nbcx));
}
```

The output will be:

```
Give n :12345
Give the position :2
give the number of digits of the number to extract :2

The result after the amber extract from position 2 on the right and the number of digits 2 is : 23
```

---

**UPDATE: Library restriction**
If for whatever reason you are not allowed to use `math.h` or `stdlib.h` you can:

- Re-implement `pow` reading: [Write Pow Function Without math.h in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525536/write-pow-function-without-math-h-in-c)
- Re-implement `abs` reading: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096354/13775483)
- Re-implement the digit counter: [C program to count number of digits in an integer](https://codeforwin.org/2016/10/c-program-to-count-number-of-digits-in-number.html)

Comment: the code is not working correctly ...


Give n: 12345
Give the position: 2
give the number of digits of the number to extract: 2

The result after the amber extract from position 2 on the right and the number of digits 2 is: 23

Comment: @MEDLDN Wait sorry what's the problem? The 2 digits of 12345 from the 2 position are 23.. that's correct. I misunderstand the question or some parameter?

Comment: The 2 digits of 12345 from the 2 position are 34 ,you start count position from the right to the left and extract 2 numbers also from the right to the left

Comment: @MEDLDN Absolutely not, and the results that this code provide are exactly the one provided by the code you mark as answer. The only thing that could create misunderstanding is whether to start counting the first digit with index 0 or index 1. I am counting from index 1. Sorry but I really can't see the problem, if there is

Comment: Ah, mine sorta works by accident then. Based only on the example I assumed it was a 1-based count from the left to find the start of extraction and then extract X digits from there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja well your code and mine provide the same results.. so, you got the problem?

Comment: My *guess* based on the single sample given was pos was 1-based from the left. If it is supposed to be from the right then the concept stays the same but the math would be a bit different. The problem description is vague and open to interpretation.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have absolutely interpreted the request like you. The problem then is that I don't understand how your output can be interpreted as correct "by accident".

Comment: Bad choice of words, sorry. It *works* because nobody noticed the numbers I used for `pos` wouldn't produce the same output if you're supposed to count from the right. I assume that for this result counting from the right that `pos` would need to be 4 since I added 2 digits to the number I used for testing. `Num: 1234567, Pos: 2, Digits: 3 - Result: 234`

Comment: @MEDLDN well, I have updated the answer with a solution that count the position from right and not from left. This also semplify the code.