# Custom implementation of Math.Exp with Big Decimal in Java

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, exponent

I have an Algorithmic implementation which deal in extremely small and extremely large values.
I am using

```
BigDecimalMath result = BigDecimalMath.exp(a) 
//where a is any bigdecimal value
```

BigDecimalMath library can be found here
https://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v2/anc

According to my best knowledge this function calculate only upto E9 (i.e -3.44E9) but my smallest value is -3.47E14 (for which it give overflow error)
I am implementing this Algorithm  in JAVA as it already implemented in other programming languages so I have to find the solution for this problem.

Can anyone help in this with or without using this library.

Comment: What is BigDecimalMath? Is it part of java? If you mean groovy implementation, you should mention it in tags at least.

Comment: Please check, I have updated the question with library detail.

Comment: take a look at: [Power by squaring for negative exponents](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)

Comment: Implementing this is going to be _extremely_ hard.  You're probably going to have to use the Taylor series expansion for exponentiation and also figure out how to calculate to a specified precision, because most results will be irrational.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it is not that hard to code ... also no need for Taylor series [`log2,exp2` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18169727/2521214) is enough and can be significantly speeded up by LUT of `0.5^(2^i)` The only problem is the `e` constant ...