# assembly armv7 neon power function

Tags: assembly, neon

I'm new to assembler. 
I want to implement a power function but i don't have an exp or a log function.
I have something like `a^b` while a is an integer and b is a float.

I could only come up with something if b is a natural number. Like an loop which multiplies a with a for b times.

Is there something like that or has anyone an idea how to implement it.

Comment: Here is [Simple ARM NEON optimized sin, cos, log and exp](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/neon_mathfun.html) with zlib license. Haven't used it, but you could test it. Having log and exp it's possible to implement pow.

Comment: I don't understand any line of this could you explain it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you asked about how to implement `pow` function using arm neon.

Most effective `pow` implementation for integer `a` and `b` is multiple `a` by `a` in a loop `abs(b)` times. For negative `b` divide 1.0 by result of the loop (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2882819/1101537)).

If you have `exp` and `log` implementations, than you could implement `pow` using equation pow(x, m) = exp(m * log (x)) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1376005/1101537)).

You mention about you don't have `exp` and `log` function.

So, if you find a math library with `exp` and `log` functions, than you can implement `pow` for double `a` and `b`.

There are some math libraries for arm, with `pow` implementation. See [math-neon](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/neon_mathfun.html), for example.

Also the is pure `log` and `exp` implementations (in C, using neon intrinsics) in the library [Simple ARM NEON optimized sin, cos, log and exp](https://code.google.com/p/math-neon/source/browse/trunk/math_powf.c). You can take the code from the library and rewrite it into arm assembly. Just ask lawyer how to satisfy library license. You need only two functions from it. Intrinsics code could be simple ported to asm.